# PL/SQL: numeric or value error only in the case of a DBMS_LOB.copy() inside a while loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

The requirement is to copy a clob object to another. Since the source clob object is large, I was initially getting a 'numeric or value error'. So I decided to perform the copy function inside a while loop, by breaking the amount copied to 2000 in one interation, which is as follows

```
temp := 0;
 WHILE temp < 10000 LOOP
     DBMS_LOB.COPY(DEST_DOC, SRC_DOC, 2000, length(DEST_DOC) + 1, temp + 1); 
     temp := temp + 2000;
END LOOP;
```

Using 10000 only for example purposes. Ideally it should have been the size of the SRC_DOC. But this throws the same error. Although the statement without the loop which is well over 10000 (or any number for that matter)

```
DBMS_LOB.COPY(DEST_DOC, SRC_DOC, 2000, length(DEST_DOC) + 1, 10000 + 1)
```

doesn't throw any error and works just as intended. I am stuck on this for days. Would be greatly appreciable if someone  could provide a solution. The total size of the SRC_DOC is 7,80,876.

Comment: Can you supply the declarations of the variables involved (namely `temp`, `dest_doc` )?

Comment: @collapsar the declarations are as follows `dest_doc clob;src_doc clob;temp number;`

Comment: @collapsar I have found out the reason for this. It's as stupid as the logging system it provides. The higher the number of bytes I was trying to copy, I was facing the error. Hence I have been assuming that it's because of the copy statement. But apparently there's a dbms_output.put_line statement which causes the error due to buffer overflow due to object size increase after copy. Thanks a lot, anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong kind of lob locator for your copy operation. Go along the following lines (The sql statements my be superfluous, of course, depending on your contextual code):

```
declare
   l_dest_doc CLOB;
   l_src_doc  CLOB;
begin
   select <whatever> into l_src_doc from <wherever>;
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_dest_doc, false);
   dbms_lob.append(l_dest_doc, l_src_doc);
   insert into <trgtable> ( ..., <trgcolumn>, ...) values ( ..., l_dest_doc, ...);
end;
```

Comment: I tried using dbms_lob.append() instead of dbms_lob.copy(). I am initializing both the clobs. For checking that I have printed their lengths just before the append statement `srcDOC:878421
destDOC:71` and I am getting the 'numeric or value' error. And just commenting the statement doesn't throw the error.

Comment: @sriram_koushik Can you show the statement by which you assign a value to your dest lob ? Do you run into  the same problem using a virgin dest lob ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you were getting error because of the size of the original object. Generally, if there are no restrictions mentioned in the documentation we should assume any reasonable size may be used.

For instance, the following line works well for and object of 1M size:

```
dbms_lob.copy(dest_doc, src_doc, length(src_doc));
```

My suggestion is that LOB locator for `DEST_DOC` might not have been initialized. Will running `dbms_lob.createtemporary(dest_doc,true);` before copying solve the issue?

Also please provide the ORA- number for the error and its full text.

**Update:**

Please provide the runnable code that gives you the error. The code below works for me on 10.2

```
declare
  SRC_DOC clob := rpad('*',20000,'*');
  DEST_DOC clob := rpad('-',10,'-');
  temp number;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('src_doc:'||length(src_doc)||'; dest_doc:'||length(dest_doc));
  temp := 0;
  WHILE temp < 10000 LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.COPY(DEST_DOC, SRC_DOC, 2000, length(DEST_DOC) + 1, temp + 1); 
    temp := temp + 2000;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('src_doc:'||length(src_doc)||'; dest_doc:'||length(dest_doc));
end;
```

And the result is

```
src_doc:20000; dest_doc:10
src_doc:20000; dest_doc:10010
```

However if I update `DEST_DOC` declaration to simply `DEST_DOC clob;` I get the following error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275
```

Comment: Well, to begin with that, that doesn't solve the problem. And no. The maximum size is limited by LOBMAXSIZE https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/2662.dbms-lob-copy . And the error I am getting is ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: @sriram_koushik Initialize your destination lob anyway or show any assignments to it after the declaration. If there are none, your code _will fail_ (regardless whether or not there are other issues).

Comment: @collapsar I am initializing the destination lob and am assigning a value before the copy operation. It still throws the same error. I am printing their lengths before copy using dbms_output and this is output `srcDOC:878421
destDOC:71`